# Provision AWS account with terraform, restricted to organization unit

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, account

We want to provision AWS accounts programmatically with terraform.

The documentation of https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/organizations_account
clearly states that

> Account management must be done from the organization's root account.

However, we want to limit permissions of account used by terraform to some organizational unit.

For example let's say there is a following organizational unit (OU) hierarchy:

```
root
└services       < terraform must not change this
│└fixed-account
│
└customers      < terraform can manage accounts in the 'customers' OU and nowhere else
 └account-1
 └account-2
```

Is it possible to limit permissions of account used by terraform to some organizational unit (OU)? Or maybe there is some trick which allows to use a different, non-root account?

Comment: I don't think there is a different way of adding an account to an organization. You have to link it to the root account somehow. The only thing that comes to mind is that you could use a data source (which is a read operation) to fetch the information and provision the account.